# How to create a CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which I think would be easier to read if it is included in the CSS. Not sure of how to. Need help.

```
<div id="prepage" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5); height:100%; width:100%; display:none; opacity:1.5"> 
        <table width="600px" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">
                    <div style="width:600px; position:relative;">
                        <div id="closeIcon" style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:0px; height:32px; width:32px; background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');background-position: 0 0px; cursor:pointer; display:none" onClick="hide();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
                        <div id="leftIcon" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:150px; height:32px; width:32px; background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');background-position: 0 -36px; cursor:pointer; display:none" onClick="prevPic();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
                        <img id="largeImg" name="largeImg" src="Original/01.jpg" border="0" style="width:480px; height:300px;" onMouseOver="showIcon();" onMouseOut="hideIcon();">
                        <div id="rightIcon" style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:150px; height:32px; width:32px; background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png'); background-position: 0 -72px; cursor:pointer; display:none" onClick="nextPic();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And I have tried the following but it is not working as I do not know how to differentiate between the div's

```
        .large div div{
            position:absolute; 
            right:10px; 
            top:0px; 
            height:32px; 
            width:32px; 
            background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
            background-position: 0 0px; 
            cursor:pointer; 
            display:none;
        }
        .large div div{
            position:absolute; 
            left:130px; 
            top:150px; 
            height:32px; 
            width:32px; 
            background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
            background-position: 0 -36px; 
            cursor:pointer; 
            display:none; 
        }
        .large div div{
            position:absolute; 
            right:10px; 
            top:150px; 
            height:32px; 
            width:32px; 
            background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
            background-position: 0 -72px; 
            cursor:pointer; 
            display:none;
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Have you read a book or tutorial on the basics of CSS stylesheets?

Comment: check this out http://www.quackit.com/css/external_style_sheets.cfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so...

```
<div id="prepage"> 
 <table width="600px" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td align="right" valign="middle">
    <div id="outerDiv">
     <div id="closeIcon" onClick="hide();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
     <div id="leftIcon" onClick="prevPic();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
     <img id="largeImg" name="largeImg" src="Original/01.jpg" border="0" onMouseOver="showIcon();" onMouseOut="hideIcon();">
     <div id="rightIcon" onClick="nextPic();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

 <style>

    #outerDiv {
        width:600px; 
        position:relative;
    }

    #prepage {
        position: absolute; 
        left:0px; 
        top:0px; 
        background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5); 
        height:100%; 
        width:100%; 
        display:none; 
        opacity:1.5;
    }

    #closeIcon {
        position:absolute; 
        right:10px; 
        top:0px; 
        height:32px; 
        width:32px; 
        background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
        background-position: 0 0px; 
        cursor:pointer; display:none;
    }

    #leftIcon {
        position:absolute; 
        left:130px; 
        top:150px; 
        height:32px; 
        width:32px; 
        background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
        background-position: 0 -36px; 
        cursor:pointer; 
        display:none;
    }

    #largeImg {
        width:480px; 
        height:300px;
    }

    #rightIcon {
        position:absolute; 
        right:10px; 
        top:150px; 
        height:32px; 
        width:32px; 
        background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png'); 
        background-position: 0 -72px; 
        cursor:pointer; 
        display:none;
    }

    </style>
```

Comment: op could easily take what is between <style> tags and include in external file if they wanted.

Comment: @themerlinproject Good work and You deserved upvote. Given.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to success:

- Pull out the value of the style attributes.
- include them in the element's class or id like so:

  ```
  #id {
      style-attribute1: style-attribute-value1;
      style-attribute2: style-attribute-value2;
      ... ect. ...
  }

  .class {
      style-attribute1: style-attribute-value1;
      style-attribute2: style-attribute-value2;
       ... ect. ...
  }
  ```

  - save the file as `style.css` in the root of your project
  - include the stylesheet in your html by placing the tag below in the `<head></head>` tag:

    `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`